# Structure of stabilizer of nonsingular line in $\Omega(7,q)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $q$ be a prime power, $\varepsilon=\pm$, and $M$ be the stabilizer of a nonsingular line in $\Omega(7,q)$ such that $M=\Omega^\varepsilon(6,q).2$. Then can we know more explicit structure of $M$? In particular, for which $q$ is $M=SO^\varepsilon(6,q)$? I only know $M=SO^\varepsilon(6,q)$ when $q$ is even (if I'm wrong please point it out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $\Omega^\epsilon(6,q).2$ is the stabilizer of a nonsingular point in $\Omega(7,q)$ rather than a nonsingular line.

When $q$ is even, there is a unique ".2" extension, which is indeed ${\rm SO}^\epsilon(6,q)$. When $q$ is odd the extension is by an element of ${\rm GO}(6,q)$ of determinant $-1$, which is not the same as ${\rm SO}^\epsilon(6,q)$. You can describe this uniformly for $q$ both odd and even as an extension of $\Omega(6,q)$ by its graph automorphism.